# How to tell browser to use specific interface, ignore routing

Tags: vb.net, browser, routes, ppp

Is it somehow possible to tell the browser to choose a specific interface and ignore the Windows routing table?

I have the following problem:
I have a PPP dial-up, where I have to access some https websites, if I make my standard gateway point to this PPP interface, I can access the website.

But I don't want to add a specific route, as I connect to different devices, and all have different IP Addresses, so it is also possible that my local LAN Interface, where I have my internet access, has the same IP Address as the remote https address I need to connect to.

So I think the only way would be to somehow tell the browser to use a specific interface for all the traffic. Is this somehow possible, or possible with VB.net programming?

Comment: I don't know what sort of system this is on, but what you want is to setup a static route for the websites that need to go through the PPP interface.  I'm no expert on how to do that, but Google that and it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer, I don't want/can't to go the way with static routes. I can't use admin right all the time on the pc, and I would need to make a new route every time I connect to another device. That's why I would like to have a program, where it creates a PPP connection with the specified remote address ( this should be no problem ) and after that I would like to access my https service.

Answer (score 0):

"Is it somehow possible to tell the browser to choose a specific interface and ignore the Windows routing table?"

No. As an application, the browser relies entirely on the OS's network stack to establish communication.

The point of a network is to allow many-to-many communication. So, if you do it right, you can use a single network adapter to communication with hundreds or even thousands of other nodes at the same time.

You could use a NIC to establish a PPPoE session to the Internet while at the same time communicating with your local network. However, this in turn requires you to connect the modem to the LAN as well which is not a good idea - you should either use two separate NICs or an Internet router.

Comment: Hello, ok that's very bad.
But it is e.g. not possible to have a LAN interface with e.g. 192.168.0.1, where I connect via RDP, and a PPP connection with e.g. 10.10.10.10, and via this PPP interface I need to connect to a PC which has 192.168.0.1 on the remote side. Am I right?

Comment: You can't have the exact same address in different networks or route your local address somewhere else. Otherwise this is completely possible.